# check if text contained in a font tag

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Im using selenium in python in order to check if a text between font tags in contained and getting the tag tbody back if it is.

the html code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" bgcolor="#000000" height="80">
    <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="#666699">
            <td height="17" bgcolor="#CCCC99">
                <font size="2"><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">PARTY 1</font></b></font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            some html code...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see the this is an example i need to check in the html page if the  has PARTY 1 in it and if so getting the tbody element back.
I should say that there is no way to get the element using id because there are other tables written in the same way.
I'v already tried using //font[contains(.,'PARTY 1')] but as it didnt worked

what is the best way to use selenium and check if PARTY 1 is in the  and get tbody elment back??

Comment: `//font[contains(.,'PARTY 1')]` should at least locate the `font` element correctly. Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This xpath return TBODY tag which contains FONT tag with 'PARTY 1' text:

`//tbody[.//font[contains(.,'PARTY 1')]]`

Comment: hey it doesnt work the text between the font tag start and end isnt recognize as text so it cant get it...

Comment: You might have to replace `contains(.,'PARTY 1')` with `contains(text(),'PARTY 1')`. Though I'm not entirely sure about that

Comment: well as i understand this text is a string in the tag and not a text this is why i cant get it when im using text() any way to check if a tag contains a string?

Comment: Man, this is html, this is only text/string/letters/words whatever you call it you have to use text() command ;)

Comment: well i know but somehow it doesnt work when i use text()

Comment: ok, so lets try from the begginig. What tool do you use to find elements? (I recommend FirePath for FF or just Chrome developer tools). Can you find this font tag using xpath: `//table/tbody/tr/td/font` ? Maybe the table is inside iFrame?

Comment: I just copied the html above into a file and used FirePath to check the path @kotoj provided above.  It worked fine for me.  Yeah, check if it's inside an iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

First get the font element using `el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('insert xpath here')` and then use `el.text` to get the text. You're code should look like this:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('insert xpath of font tag here')

if el.text == 'PARTY 1':
    return driver.find_element_by_xpath('insert xpath of tbody here')
```